# How do I check if my router is patched against the KRACK exploit?

Tags: wifi, wpa2, krack

Numerous Google searches found little useful information. The most comprehensive list is at http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/byvendor?searchview&Query=FIELD+Reference=228519&SearchOrder=4

and most vendors are reported as "Unknown".

Is there any way to check if my router is patched against WPA2 KRACK that doesn't involve finding and running a hack tool?

Comment: Why don't you contact the vendor and ask if the most recent firmware addresses the KRACK problem?

Comment: Well if it's unknown it's probably not patched (or unknown..). If you don't want to check and you don't want to ask the vendor you have to hope someone will test it for you.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, you only have two options wait to a vendor response or check with a tool.

If you prefer to wait, check this [list](https://github.com/kristate/krackinfo#vendor-response-complete). The list is accurate and updated frequently.

On the other hand, I think that you should check yourself the router using the [krack-ft-test](https://github.com/vanhoefm/krackattacks-test-ap-ft), released by the author who discovered the vulnerability. Remember that this tool only tests the vulnerability you are not doing and aggressive attack.